# How to get the first subset of related items from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of filenames, as such:

```
D-CGRS_SS-2000_BLUE.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2000_GREEN.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2000_LIME.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2000_NAVY.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2000_RED.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2000_WHITE.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2000_YELLOW.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2001_BLUE.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2001_GREEN.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2001_LIME.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2001_NAVY.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2001_RED.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2001_WHITE.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2001_YELLOW.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2002_BLUE.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2002_GREEN.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2002_LIME.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2002_NAVY.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2002_RED.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2002_WHITE.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2002_YELLOW.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2003_BLUE.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2003_GREEN.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2003_LIME.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2003_NAVY.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2003_RED.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2003_WHITE.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2003_YELLOW.jpg
.
.
.
```

What is the best way to go about paring this list down to just the first seven items? The ones that all have the same "SS" number (SS-2000)? So the resulting array would just be:

```
D-CGRS_SS-2000_BLUE.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2000_GREEN.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2000_LIME.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2000_NAVY.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2000_RED.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2000_WHITE.jpg
D-CGRS_SS-2000_YELLOW.jpg
```

**EDIT:**

Thank you for your responses. I should have been more clear about my request before posting it, however. My apologies. Here are some additional restrictions:

The `SS-2000` portion will not always be `SS-2000`. In some directories, the series begins with `SS-1900` or `SS-1806` or whatever.

Also, I cannot guarantee that there will always be 7 in each group. Some might have 3 or 12 or whatever.

Finally, I cannot guarantee that the first two digits will be `SS`, but it *will* be either `SS`, `HA`, or `NH`.

After a good night's sleep and reading your responses, I may have come up with an idea: I might want to use `preg_match` on the *very first element* in the array to find the pattern `/(SS|HA|NH)-\d{4}/`, then use the `$matches[0]` result as the pattern for a `preg_grep` on the array. (Feel free to reply with a simplification that RegEx pattern, if it can be.)

Comment: use `array_filter` with a filter function that compares the beginning of the filename with the beginning of the first element.

Comment: Is it always the first 7 elements, or can the number of matching elements vary?

Comment: Can there be other matching elements later in the array? Should they be included, or do you only want the ones at the beginning?

Comment: Should it only compare the SS number, or also the D-CGRS prefix?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: So, it appears I cannot even answer my own question anymore. I guess enough people hated my question that it has been summarily buried. At any rate, the last paragraph of my edit sums it up nicely. It worked with the constraints and will work for future cases.

Comment: Thank you, @Barmar, for recognizing that there were other constraints at play here that precludes the use of a simple `array_filter`, `array_slice`, `strpos`, etc.

Comment: They didn't "hate" your question. It was closed because it was unclear and seemed like other questions already answered it. That was before you added clarifications that distinguished it.

Comment: I've reopened the question, you can now post your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is always the first seven item in array use [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) as:

```
$onlyFirstSeven = array_slice($originalArray, 0, 7);
```

If you looking for all starting with the same prefix use `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($originalArray as $item)    
    if (strpos($item, 'D-CGRS_SS-2000') === 0) {
        $res[] = $item;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If by the first 7 items you mean to get the images with this prefix `D-CGRS_SS-2000` and the position in the array does not matter, you might use a pattern to match those names which will match from the start `^` till the end `$` of the string and matches the color names using `[A-Z]+` for uppercase characters.

If for example you array of filenames is `$filenames`, one option is to use [preg_grep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
$filteredFilenames = preg_grep("~^D-CGRS_SS-2000_[A-Z]+\.jpg$~", $filenames);
print_r($filteredFilenames);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => D-CGRS_SS-2000_BLUE.jpg
    [1] => D-CGRS_SS-2000_GREEN.jpg
    [2] => D-CGRS_SS-2000_LIME.jpg
    [3] => D-CGRS_SS-2000_NAVY.jpg
    [4] => D-CGRS_SS-2000_RED.jpg
    [5] => D-CGRS_SS-2000_WHITE.jpg
    [6] => D-CGRS_SS-2000_YELLOW.jpg
)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/mUtTV)

Answer (score 0):

> I might want to use `preg_match` on the very first element in the array to find the pattern `/(SS|HA|NH)-\d{4}/`, then use the `$matches[0]` result as the pattern for a `preg_grep` on the array.

I gave that a try today and that works! Thanks to everyone who responded with their potential solutions, but this one gets the job done with all the constraints I edited into my original question.